# Getting started with JSF - Richfaces on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, richfaces

I used to work with JSF - Richfaces but had no idea of how to start it and I quit before I learned it.

Is there any easy way to start? What do I need to add. Like splitting projects into 4 or so and what server to use, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can also find many RichFaces resources on my blog:

https://maxkatz.net/tag/richfaces-howto/

including this project template:

https://maxkatz.net/2010/04/15/the-easiest-way-to-start-with-richfaces/

Comment: Link expired. Please update it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [hello world](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html) and [Practical Richfaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=yE_3TRwuUZkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=JSF+-+Richfaces+book&source=bl&ots=I4WZ0MFY4S&sig=528TjrzIefNAZfgtqMTILscsvyM&hl=en&ei=kbMUTZ_ZD4SV8QPg0MGFBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=JSF%20-%20Richfaces%20book&f=false)

But I suggest you to use [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf?theme=aristo). I think primefaces is the best among jsf components because of its ajax and ui facilities

Comment: Each of the component libraries has its strength. The Richfaces datatable is considerably more powerful. Unfortunately you can't realiably use it with JSF 2 until RichFaces 4 comes out...

Comment: I started following this tutorial, but I download Richfaces 4 I believe. When i got on "3.2.4. Registering bean in faces-config.xml", I couldn't find faces-config. Where it should be? I started a project as Dynamic Web Project, should it be something else?

Answer (score 3):

although I don't have a tutorial to suggest to you, I would recommend when experimenting with Richfaces components, to look them up in the [live demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf), where code snippets and examples are shown. For each component you can find additional information in the "Developer Guide" link in the upper left corner.

As far as Eclipse is concerned and since you are using Richfaces, I would definitely use install the [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation.html) plugin, which has handy features, such as auto-complete, visual editing etc.