# Apache Tomcat, Eclipse, JBoss, and RichFaces

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat, richfaces

## Background

Configure the latest version of Eclipse to use the latest version of RichFaces.

## Problem

After reading various sources and following scores of steps, I have not been able to create a RichFaces page using the latest version of Eclipse and RichFaces.

## Resources

- http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=723
- http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html
- [Getting started with JSF - Richfaces on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526850/getting-started-with-jsf-richfaces-on-eclipse)
- [Practical RichFaces](http://books.google.com/books?id=yE_3TRwuUZkC&printsec=frontcover)

## Questions

Where can I find up-to-date documentation for a **working** and **comprehensive** example of creating a **simple** RichFaces page using the latest version of Eclipse and RichFaces? The documentation must include:

- How to install Eclipse
- How to install RichFaces for Eclipse
- How to create a **simple** web page that uses RichFaces
- How to deploy that web page to an instance of Apache Tomcat

JBoss is an option, but I cannot find a complete and working example of how to install RichFaces (using JBoss' Web Tools plugin, or just by itself) with Eclipse.

Every resource I have found is either outdated, missing steps, or technically incorrect.

Many thanks!

Comment: Information overflow, although relevant questions.

Comment: would be great to limit a posting to one question an make that one short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help get you started: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2011/02/updated-easiest-way-to-start-with-richfaces-3/.

Comment: Thanks for this. I already went through your steps. The instructions are missing a large number of tasks. From creating a new JSP/JSF page to deploying to Apache Tomcat. Also, the instructions are outdated with respect to the latest versions of JBoss and Eclipse.

Comment: @Dave: Using Eclipse 3.6 and JBoss Tools 3.2 - you use the same instructions. First download and install Eclipse 3.6 for Java EE developers, then install JBoss Tools (Dev) 3.2: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_2.html. Then, you can import the RichFaces template again.

Comment: @Dave: My post has instructions on how to deploy to Tomcat as well. Let me know if you are able to launch the application.

Comment: I already went through all those steps. The result was `404 Not Found: index.jsf`. I will try again, cleanly, and email you the exact steps.

Comment: @Dave: Run index.jsp (or start.jsf).